# Will Oracle ASM add data file to a tablespace automatically?

Tags: oracle11gr2, oracle-rac

If a tablespace has 1 data file(limit is 32gb), and the datafile has extended to its maximum, Will ASM automatically handle **adding of the datafile** or should I manually use the below statement to add a datafile to the tablespace.

```
alter tablespace TS_MASTER add datafile '+DATA' size 1g autoextend on;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes ,you need to manually add the datafile to the tablespace,ASM will not automatically add the Datafile,If you need to Add the Datafile Automatically when the tablespace reaches a particular threshold you need to  create a SCHEDULER Job or DBMS_JOB or Shell script that will monitor the tablespace space and when it reaches a particular threshold it should automatically add the datafile.